# Is there a compatability issue for VBA between Excel 2007 and Excel 2010 or newer?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not a VBA expert and have only just started doing some VBA work at a new job. Some users have Office 2007 on Windows XP computers while others have Office 2010 or 2013 on Windows 7 computers. The workbooks have been fine until the end of March when the 2007 versions started doing rounding differently on some cells, if they even show numbers because sometimes they just show the pound sign. If a user opens the same workbook in Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 it's fine. Is this a problem that could be fixed or is it just incompatibility?

Comment: I know you didn't mention date formats but your situation sounds similar to mine. So please elaborate: What is the number/date format on the problem cells?

Comment: I have Office 2010 and when I check the format I see that it's number format with 1 decimal. I will check one of the older XP machines and see what format theirs is.

Answer (score 1):

In general any workbooks are fully compatible between 2007 through the most recent version.

We did experience a problem with certain workbooks. These were created with Excel 2007 on Win XP. We now have Win7 and Excel 2010 and Excel 2013; also we still have the Win XP with Excel 2007. It is not a shared workbook, but we pass it back and forth to make changes.

Occasionally we have problems with cells formatted "General". They change to date format spontaneously (they would show as pound signs ###### as the cell was too narrow). I don't understand the cause fully but when it happens it affects cells with "General format". Just change the date format to a number format and the problem is fixed. It was a massive workbook and was a massive problem.

I noticed that whenever something is copied into the workbook it creates new cell styles. We had hundreds of cell styles in the workbook. All of the problems had one of the new cell styles. When I changed the cell format in the cell style to a number format it then stayed that way.

The problem cell formats were usually a date format. When I looked at the date format it was usually a regionally dependent date format. When you format a cell, select Date category and choose a type of format with a star it is regionally dependent. So I changed the date format to a format that is not regionally dependent and that seemed to help.
[image]

So to recap:

- I deleted all cell styles but a few
- All remaining cell styles do not specify number format
- I changed all cells with numbers to a format other than General
- I avoid regionally dependent date formats

My theory is that the cell styles got corrupted to a date format somehow. So now I avoid cell styles dictating number formats. There may be other ways of dealing with this but this worked for me.

Sounds crazy but is true. We now have a stable workbook, but it was a huge investment to fix all of it.

Some relevant pages

[Excel 2007 spontaneously formats entire work book in date format](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-2007-spontaneously-formats-entire-work-book/1ae533af-ecee-41fa-866a-2590343a111d)

[Similar problem](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/507649-why-does-excel-change-cell-format-date.html)

[Similar problem](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/501123-format-continues-change-date.html)

[Stop automatically changing numbers to dates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)